# C# equivalent for this regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have this regular expression pattern: `.{2}\@.{2}\K|\..*(*SKIP)(?!)|.(?=.*\.)`

It works perfectly to convert to replace the matches to get

```
trabc@abtrec.com.lo => ***bc@ab*****.com.lo

demomail@demodomain.com => ******il@de*********.com
```

But when I try to use it on C# the \K and the (*SKIP) and (*F) are not allowed.

what will be the c# version of this pattern? or do you know a simpler way to mask the email without the unsupported pattern entries?

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wEpq1Z/)

**UPDATE:**

(*SKIP): this verb causes the match to fail at the current starting position in the subject if the rest of the pattern does not match

(*F): Forces a matching failure at the given position in the pattern (the same as (?!)

Comment: Since as you've observed they aren't valid C# things you might want to explain what they do. You're going to get mostly c# people looking at this question who don't know what they do...

Comment: I just update the patter and add a detail for *SKIP

Comment: You can also take a look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCRE.NET

Comment: You may not know this but when `.{2}\@.{2}\K` matches something, the result of the replace is to inject an asterisk at the current position _just past it_. This doesn't represent any kind of masking I know of since your adding a character that, positionaly wasn't  there before.

Comment: Also, this .{2}\@`.{2}`\K  portion will match the dot character. You need to make changes to prevent that. Also, you're not going to be able to get an equivalent of this term `.{2}\@.{2}\K` when using this term `.(?=.*\.)` if doing a simple replacement. You have to use a delegate callback. So, by removing the `\K` and the `(*SKIP)(?!)` and adding capture groups, you'll know what to replace and what to skip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\w(?=.{2,}@)|(?<=@[^\.]{2,})\w
```

**[Click for Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cw%28%3F%3D.%7B2%2C%7D%40%29%7C%28%3F%3C%3D%40%5B%5E%5C.%5D%7B2%2C%7D%29%5Cw&i=trabc%40abtrec.com.lo%0D%0Ademomail%40demodomain.com&r=*)**

**Explanation:**

- `\w` - matches a word character
- `(?=.{2,}@)` - positive lookahead to find the position immediately followed by 2+ occurrences of any character followed by `@`
- `|` - OR
- `(?<=@[^\.]{2,})` - positive lookbehind to find the position immediately preceded by `@` followed by 2+ occurrences of any character that is not a `.`
- `\w` - matches a word character.

Replace each match with a `*`

Comment: `ai@PP.emodomain.com` nothing masked.

Comment: @sln Yes it would not mask anything. Looking at his original regex, it seemed that he didnot want 2 characters immediately preceding `@` and 2 characters immediately following `@` to be masked. Hence, such a solution

Comment: Yeah. Also, your sol'n doesn't address this `.{2}\@.{2}\K` which he uses to _insert_  an `*` rather than replace. I wish people would take the train to the right station instead of one close to the destination.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same result with a regex that matches items in one block, and applying a custom match evaluator:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(
    s
,   @"^.*(?=.{2}\@.{2})|(?<=.{2}\@.{2}).*(?=.com.*$)"
,   match => new string('*', match.ToString().Length)
);
```

The regex has two parts:

- The one on the left `^.*(?=.{2}\@.{2})` matches the user name portion except the last two characters
- The one on the right `(?<=.{2}\@.{2}).*(?=.com.*$)` matches the suffix of the domain up to the ".com..." ending.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/3X5J9T)